# How to run a method in Java using a timer?

Tags: java

How would I have this method run every couple of seconds in a recursive function.
I want the i variable to update by 1 every couple of seconds than print it to the console.
In javascript I could use setTimeout is there a method like the javascript setTimeout in Java?

```
final i = 0;
public void timerActions() {
     i = i + 1;
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: you can use `Thread.sleep(1000);` if this is just for fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with Timer

```
Timer timer = new Timer("Display Timer");

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                timerActions();
            }
        };
        // This will invoke the timer every second
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ScheduledExecutorService` for that.

*Update* per Peter Lawrey comment (thanks):

Methods :

```
public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command,
                                              long initialDelay,
                                              long period,
                                              TimeUnit unit);
```

and

```
public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable command,
                                                 long initialDelay,
                                                 long delay,
                                                 TimeUnit unit);
```

can be used in order to achieve your desired behavior.

Comment: schedule only does it once.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `Thread` to sleep after execution if it's just a simple application which just has to "run slower".

For example:

```
final i = 0;
public void timerActions() {
    i++;
    System.out.println(i);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

1000 in the parentheses means 1000ms=1second - the amount of time in which the thread sleeps.
This is a simple way to do it, but be aware that in larger multi-threaded applications you have to take into acount thread safety and related problems.

Documentation for [Thread.sleep()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TimedAction
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("begin");

        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        Runnable command = new Runnable()
        {
            private int i = 0;

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // put your logic HERE
                System.out.println(i++);
            }
        };

        // execute command, immediately (0 delay), and every 2 seconds
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(command, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        System.in.read();

        executor.shutdownNow();
        executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print "Counting..." on every 2 seconds

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

private int counter = 0;

public void run() {
    counter++;
    if (counter <= 3) {
        System.out.println("Counting - counter = " + counter);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Stopping timer execution");
        this.cancel();
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Timer timer = new Timer("TimerThreadName");
    MyTimerTask task = new MyTimerTask();

    // void java.util.Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 2000);

    }
}
```